# Ocultar un BottomNavigationView en Android usando Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy creando una app solamente con fragmentos y uso de `BottomNavigationView` para implementar su cambio de vistas pero en una de ellas tiene que acceder a un fragmento detalle y es donde se deberia ocultar el `BottomNavigationView`

Answer (score 0):

Para ocultar y mostrar el `BottomNavigationView` dependiendo del fragmento si pertanece al grupo de fragmenots de la barra inferior, con animación

```kotlin
supportFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
    override fun onFragmentViewCreated(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment, v: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.root, Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM).excludeTarget(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, true))
        when (f) {
            is DetailFragment -> {
                binding.navView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            else -> {
                binding.navView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
}, true)
```

para que todo funcione correctamente se debe encapsular en un `CoordinatorLayout`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="?attr/actionBarPopupTheme" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Si queremos que la barra inferior se oculte al desplazar por una lista `recyclerView` etc... `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"`